# Need some explanation about trees in C

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

```
Leaf *findLeaf(Leaf *R,int data)
{
  if(R->data >= data )
  {
    if(R->left == NULL) return R;
    else return findLeaf(R->left,data);
  }
  else
  {
     if(R->right == NULL) return R;
     else return findLeaf(R->right,data);
  }
}


void traverse(Leaf *R)
{
 if(R==root){printf("ROOT is %d\n",R->data);}
 if(R->left != NULL)
 {
    printf("Left data %d\n",R->left->data);
    traverse(R->left);
 }
 if(R->right != NULL)
 {
    printf("Right data %d\n",R->right->data);
    traverse(R->right);
 }
}
```

These code snippets works fine but i wonder how they works?
I need a brief explanation about recursion.I am thankful for your helps.

Comment: [Start here.](http://google.com/search?q=recursion)

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319426/need-some-explanation-about-trees-in-c :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Leaf` struct will look something like this:

```
typedef struct struct_t {
    int data;
    Leaf * left;   //These allow structs to be chained together where each node 
    Leaf * right;  //has two pointers to two more nodes, causing exponential
} Leaf;            //growth.
```

The function takes a pointer to a Leaf we call `R` and some data to search against, it returns a pointer to a Leaf

```
Leaf *findLeaf(Leaf *R,int data){
```

This piece of code decides whether we should go left or right, the tree is known to be ordered because the insert function follows this same rule for going left and right.

```
  if(R->data >= data ){
```

This is an edge case of the recursive nature of the function, if we have reached the last node in a tree, called the Leaf, return that Leaf.

An edge case of a recursive function has the task of ending the recursion and returning a result. Without this, the function would not finish.

```
    if(R->left == NULL) return R;
```

This is how we walk through the tree, Here, we are traversing down the left side because the data was larger. (Larger data is always inserted on at the left to stay ordered.)
What is happening is that now we call findLeaf() with `R->left`, but imagine if we get to this point again in this next call.

It will become `R->left->left` in reference to the first call. If the data is smaller than the current node we are operating on we would go right instead.

```
    else return findLeaf(R->left,data);
```

Now we are at the case where the data was smaller than the current Node, so we are going right.

```
  } else {
```

This is exactly the same as with the left.

```
     if(R->right == NULL) return R;
     else return findLeaf(R->right,data);
  }
}
```

In the end, the return of the function can be conceptualized as something like `R->right->right->left->NULL`.

Lets take this tree and operate on it with findLeaf();

[image: BST]

`findLeaf(Leaf * root, 4) //In this example, root is already pointing to (8)`

We start at the root, at the top of the tree, which contains 8.

First we check `R->data >= data` where we know `R->data` is `(8)` and `data` is `(4)`. Since we know `data` is smaller than `R->data`(Current node), we enter the `if` statement.

Here we operate on the left Leaf, checking if it is `NULL`. It isn't and so we skip to the `else`.

Now we return `findLeaf(R->left, data);`, but to return it, we must solve it first. This causes us to enter a second iteration where we compare `(3)` to `(4)` and try again.

Going through the entire process again, we will compare `(6) to (4)` and then finally find our node when we comepare `(4) to (4)`. Now we will backtrack through the function and return a chain like this:

`R(8)->(3)->(6)->(4)`

Edit: Also, coincidentally, I wrote a blog post about traversing a linked list to explain the nature of a Binary Search Tree [here](http://needlessdetails.blogspot.com/2013/04/binary-search-tree-starting-with-lists.html).

Comment: I added in more details and a walkthrough a tree. for you @user1941070

Comment: @user1941070 Note that it's the exact same concept for the traverse function, except the edge case is just hitting the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Each Leaf contains three values:

- `data` - an integer
- `left` and `right`, both pointers to another leaf.

`left`, `right` or both, might be NULL, meaning there isn't another leaf in that direction.

So that's a tree. There's one Leaf at the root, and you can follow the trail of `left` or `right` pointers until you reach a NULL.

The key to recursion is that if you follow the path by one Leaf, the remaining problem is *exactly the same* (but "one smaller") as the problem you had when you were at the root. So you can call the same function to solve the problem. Eventually the routine will be at a Leaf with NULL as its pointer, and you've solved the problem.

It's probably easiest to understand a list before you understand a tree. So instead of a Leaf with two pointers, `left` and `right`, you have a Node with just one pointer, `next`. To follow the list to its end, recursively:

```
Node findEnd(Node node) {
     if(node->next == NULL) {
        return node; // Solved!!
     } else {
        return findEnd(node->next);
     }
}
```

What's different about your findLeaf? Well, it uses the `data` parameter to decide whether to follow the `left` or `right` pointer, but otherwise it's exactly the same.

You should be able to make sense of `traverse()` with this knowledge. It uses the same principle of recursion to visit every Leaf in the structure.

Answer (score 1):

A little comment about recursion and then a little comment about searching on a tree:

let's suppose you want to calculate n!. You can do (pseudocode)

```
fac 0     = 1
fac (n+1) = (n+1) * fac n
```

So recursion is solving a problem by manipulating the result of solving the same problem with a smaller data. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion.

So now, let's suppose we have a data structure tree

```
T = (L, e, R)
```

with L the left subtree, e is the root and R is the right subtree... So let's say you want to find the value v in that tree, you would do

```
find v LEAF      = false // you cant find any value in an empty tree, base case
find v (L, e, R) = 

if v == e 
  then something(e) 
else
  if v < e 
    find v L  (here we have recursion, we say 'go and search for v in the left subtree)
  else
    find v R  (here we have recursion, we say 'go and search for v in the right subtree)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a function that breaks a problem down into 2 variants:

1. one step of solving the problem, and calling itself with the remainder of the problem
2. the last step of solving the problem

Recursion is simply a different way of looping through code.

Comment: if we dont use return statement like in the traverse function is the working principle same?

Comment: Yes. The only difference is whether there is a return value or not. `Traverse` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive algorithms generally work hand in hand with some form of data structure - in your case the tree. You need to imagine the recursion - very high level - as "reapply the same logic on a subset of the problem".

In your case the subset of the problem is either the branch of the three on the right or the branch of the three on the left.

So, let's look at the traverse algorithm:

It takes the leaf you pass to the method and - if it's the ROOT leaf states it
Then, if there is a "left" sub-leaf it displays the data attached to it and restarts the algorithm (the recursion) which means... on the left node
If the left node is the ROOT, state it (no chance after the first recursion since the ROOT is at the top)
Then , if there is a "left" sub-leaf to our left node, display it and restart the algorithm on this left, left

When reaching the bottom left, i.e. when there is no left leaf left (following? :) ) then it does the same on the first right leaf. If there is neither a left leaf nor a right leaf, which means we are at the real leaf that does not have sub-leafs, the recursive call ends, which means that the algorithm starts again from the place it was before recursing and with all the variables at the state they were in then.

After first recursion termination, you will move from the bottom left leaf up one leaf, and go down on the right leaf if there is one and start again printing and moving on the left.

All in all - the ending result is that you walk through your whole tree in a left first way.

Tell me if it's not crystal clear and try to apply the same pattern on the findLeaf recursive algorithm.

Comment: It starts from root and goes the left most leaf then turns back from bottom to root.while turning back it visits the right leaf.when it comes to root then starts traversing to right sub tree.i understood it very well.Thank you.